# How do I install a solid state hard drive?

Tags: laptop, ssd, dell-inspiron

I have an older Dell laptop (Inspiron 1000 authentication is dated 2004). I would love to be able to repair it by putting in - external would be fine also - a solid state hard drive (the original HDD is very, very dead). An IT tech told me this was impossible; however I'm pretty determined to do this and so am still wondering if anyone knows how to do this. This is a PATA/IDE connection by the way.

**Okay, so my question is; is there any way I can put a solid state drive in or on a ten year old laptop?**

**Edit: I found a regular HDD - *not* SDD - on Ebay and I am wondering if it makes any difference who manufactured it. The original was a 30.00 GB Toshiba while the new one is a 160.00 GB Fujitsu.**

Comment: What type of HDD if it's not a SATA drive what you want is indeed not possible

Comment: @Ramhound IDE/PATA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the internal connector is IDE, and you will be unlikely to find an SSD drive that is IDE as modern drives are SATA.  If you did, it would likely be very old, and old SSD drives were small - perhaps no bigger than the 40GB already in there.  And likely a data risk as it is old.

So your only option would be a USB mounted flash drive, for which you would need a SATA to USB converter, and some hope that your Dell would be able to boot from it.  But you would not be getting much benefit from the SSD speed as you are bottlenecking it down a USB2.0 connection.

It might be more useful to use it to hold down paper when it is windy.

Comment: Believe it or not, modern PATA/IDE SSDs [are available](http://www.supertalent.com/products/ssd_product_detail.php?parent=6&category=DuraDrive&type=105) in [capacities](http://www.supertalent.com/products/ssd_product_detail.php?parent=6&category=DuraDrive&type=96) up to 256GB.

Comment: Good find!  My searching was without success.

Comment: I agree that it's probably not a good idea, but surprisingly, it's probably possible.

Comment: Thank you all for your input... I shall continue to consider whether it is worth my while to fix it or take it apart and use it for a paper weight :)

Answer (score 1):

I also use an Inspiron 1000. She may be old, but just keeps slogging along.
I tried upgrading to a SSD, but found it to be impossible, due to the bios not recognizing it. You can use a SSD for external storage on a USB connection with no problem, however, I could not get the old girl to boot from it, although it would install an OS from the CD drive and try to boot, immediately after the windows splash screen I'd get a BSOD.
A SSD would not gain you that much speed anyway, since it would be PATA instead of SATA. So, when you get your new drive, be sure it is a 7200 rpm instead of the original 5400 rpm. Brand name or size doesn't matter as long as it is IDE/PATA.